# Compile error during webpack build with ajv

Tags: typescript, webpack, ajv

I am using ajv  ("8.12.0") in a webpack typescript project. Because of the following errors in ajv webpack does not build the index.js in production mode (and I am not sure, if/how that can/should be ignored, in order to get the get the index.js anyway). In development mode the file is created and the library works just fine.

```
ERROR in [REDACTED]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/codegen/code.ts
52:4-89
[tsl] ERROR in [REDACTED]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/codegen/code.ts(52,5)
      TS2322: Type 'CodeItem' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14

ERROR in [REDACTED]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/codegen/code.ts
52:12-21
[tsl] ERROR in [REDACTED]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/codegen/code.ts(52,13)
      TS2322: Type 'CodeItem' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14

ERROR in [REDACTED]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/resolve.ts
102:2-10
[tsl] ERROR in [REDACTED]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/resolve.ts(102,3)
      TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type '{ default: { (schema: SchemaObject, opts: Options, cb?: Callback | undefined): void; (schema: SchemaObject, cb: Callback): void; }; }' has no call signatures.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14

ERROR in [REDACTED]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/resolve.ts
143:31-36
[tsl] ERROR in [REDACTED]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/resolve.ts(143,32)
      TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type '{ default: (a: any, b: any) => boolean; }' has no call signatures.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14

webpack 5.84.1 compiled with 4 errors in 37642 ms
```

this is how my webpack.config.js looks like:

```
const path = require('path');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        mergeDuplicateChunks: false,
        removeAvailableModules: true,
        usedExports: true,
        concatenateModules: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    ],
    stats: {
        errorDetails: true
    }
};
```

and my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    // commonjs, esnext
    "lib": [
      "ES2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  // Only include .ts/.tsx files in the src directory
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. It works fine for me. How did you use the `ajv`? Show the code of `index.ts` file.